# Hide cURL info from cron job output

Tags: php, curl, cron

For most of my cron jobs, I use `php /path/to/file.php > /dev/null` which allows me to only get emails if there is output streamed to `stderr`. This works great for everything apart from when there are cURL requests being executed.

Using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = true`, it won't output if I run the file from a browser,  but through cron jobs, I get an email full of the request details including connection attempts and sent/received headers.

Is there a way to either pipe this output to stdout, or preferably, remove it from the output streams entirely, as I don't want/need to see this information if I run it from a browser either.

Thanks for your time.

---

Code:

`getCURL("www.example.com", array(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => COOKIES));`

```
function getCURL($url, $opt = array()){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "someuseragent");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIES);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt);

    $response_raw = curl_exec($ch);

    $header = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "", substr($response_raw, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)));

    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header) as $i => $line){
        if ($i === 0){
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        } else {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);
            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $body = substr($response_raw, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));

    curl_close($ch);

    return array(
        "header" => $headers,
        "body" => $body,
        "cookies" => COOKIES);
}
```

Comment: add your code, so we can see exactly whats taking place

Comment: @cmorrissey I've added it in.

Comment: I think you want to set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `false`

Comment: @cmorrissey Ah, cheers mate, that sorted it out. Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `false`